# list duplicate values of rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement for fetching data in our tables.
Say, i run this :

```
select * 
from test 
where T1 IN (
              SELECT T1 
              FROM test 
              WHERE VALUE IN ('1-116P-540','1-116P-540')
            );
```

The output will be a single row since it will not give duplicate records.

In my case, I need the duplicate records to be populated with the same value.

Comment: sample data and expected output is helpful to solve problem

Comment: @pratiksharma . . . What duplicate records?  Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try using distinct clause but from your query it seems that you are passing *'1-116P-540*' value twice

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * 
 FROM test 
 WHERE T1 IN (
              SELECT T1 
              FROM test 
              WHERE VALUE IN ('1-116P-540','1-116P-540')
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sub-query is not required below query will server your purpose

```
              SELECT  distinct *  
              FROM test 
              WHERE VALUE IN ('1-116P-540','1-116P-540')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Value IN (
  SELECT value
  FROM test
  GROUP BY value
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```